# Why does my Image stretch when I run my app?

Tags: ios, storyboard, uistoryboard

When I run my app to see my sign up page, my image is stretched out but on my storyboard and previews it looks normal. See the images below for to get an idea of what I'm talking about. Do I have to edit something through Xcode or add some code?

[image: Here is the app launched]

[image: When I see it previewed on my storyboard]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we don't know what your constraints are, it's hard to tell. But try the following:

[image]

[image]